# Unix Domain Sockets: accept() not setting sun_path

Tags: linux, sockets, unix-socket

I am doing some testing with Unix domain sockets and I can communicate over them without an issue, however, when I call `accept()` on the server side of my test program, the returned `struct sockaddr_un` doesn't contain a `sun_path`.

I am pretty sure that Inet sockets have their address and port properly filled out after an `accept()` call, so am I doing something wrong in my test program or am I expecting the wrong outcome?

I am running CentOS 6.2 and gcc 4.4.6.

Sample Code:

server.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NAME "socket"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sock, msgsock, rval;
    struct sockaddr_un server, client;
    char buf[1024];

    sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("opening stream socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(server.sun_path, NAME);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un))) {
        perror("binding stream socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Socket has name %s\n", server.sun_path);
    listen(sock, 5);

    for (;;) {
        socklen_t len = sizeof(client);
        msgsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len);

        if (msgsock == -1)
            perror("accept");
        else do {
            printf("strlen(sun_path) = %zu\n", strlen(client.sun_path));

            bzero(buf, sizeof(buf));
            if ((rval = read(msgsock, buf, 1024)) < 0)
                perror("reading stream message");
            else if (rval == 0)
                printf("Ending connection\n");
            else
                printf("-->%s\n", buf);
        } while (rval > 0);

        close(msgsock);
    }
    close(sock);
    unlink(NAME);

    return 0;
}
```

client.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DATA "Half a league, half a league . . ."

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_un server;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage:%s <pathname>", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("opening stream socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(server.sun_path, argv[1]);

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server,
                sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) < 0) {
        close(sock);
        perror("connecting stream socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (write(sock, DATA, sizeof(DATA)) < 0)
        perror("writing on stream socket");

    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

Just to reiterate the question:

Why isn't `sun_path` filled out after the `accept()` call on the server?

Comment: Truly a miracle… `len` becomes `2` which is `sizeof(sa_family_t)` and according to the man this can happen only when the socket is unbound, but in your case it is clearly bound…

Comment: I also tried with abstract sockets and, again, this length is always `2` which is clearly wrong, accoring to the man page.

Comment: I think this might be normal. Like sockets returned by `socketpair()`, these types of sockets aren't bound to any path, but they are nevertheless connected to another socket at the other end.

Comment: @kirelagin thanks for the comments and effort!

Comment: @Celada I wouldn't be surprised if you are correct, I was hoping that someone could definitively tell me yes or no though. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I am really not sure if this is an answer at all. Probably it's more like musings about some research, though maybe still worth while reading.

The value filled by `accept(2)` seems to be quite protocol agnostic at least in Linux 3.16.0, NetBSD 6.1.4 and Darwin 13.1.0 kernels. In practice this means that the second parameter to `accept(2)`, `struct sockaddr *` gets filled only up to what is shared between all protocols. So what you have in your hands after a successful `acccept(2)` is far from being a complete `struct sockaddr_un`.

Probably nobody thought it would be of much importance at the time first implementations of `accept(2)` were done and now we're stuck with this. Fortunately there is a way around that, in case one has lost the pathname used for socket with call to `bind(2)`, and would now like to find it again.

With `struct sockaddr_storage` and `getsockname(2)` the member sun_path is accessible. So, to make sure you are getting all juicy details, call `getsockname(2)` after a successful call to `accept(2)` (this would be put after line number 40 in your `server.c`):

```
       struct sockaddr_storage ss;
       socklen_t sslen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);
       if (getsockname(msgsock, (struct sockaddr *)&ss, &sslen) == 0) {
               struct sockaddr_un *un = (struct sockaddr_un *)&ss;
               printf("socket name is: %s\n", un->sun_path);
       }
```

Or just use this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NAME "socket"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sock, msgsock, rval;
    struct sockaddr_un server, client;
    char buf[1024];

    sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("opening stream socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(server.sun_path, NAME);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un))) {
        perror("binding stream socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Socket has name %s\n", server.sun_path);
    listen(sock, 5);

    for (;;) {
        socklen_t len = sizeof(client);
        msgsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len);

        if (msgsock == -1)
            perror("accept");
        else do {
            printf("strlen(sun_path) = %zu\n", strlen(client.sun_path));

            struct sockaddr_storage ss;
            socklen_t sslen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);
            if (getsockname(msgsock, (struct sockaddr *)&ss, &sslen) == 0) {
                    struct sockaddr_un *un = (struct sockaddr_un *)&ss;
                    printf("socket name is: %s\n", un->sun_path);
            }

            bzero(buf, sizeof(buf));
            if ((rval = read(msgsock, buf, 1024)) < 0)
                perror("reading stream message");
            else if (rval == 0)
                printf("Ending connection\n");
            else
                printf("-->%s\n", buf);
        } while (rval > 0);

        close(msgsock);
    }
    close(sock);
    unlink(NAME);

    return 0;
}
```

This has been tested, ie. it compiles and produces expected results, to work on a GNU/Linux system running kernel 3.16.0, a NetBSD system running 6.1.4 kernel, and a system equipped with OS/X Mavericks, running 13.1.0 kernel. In all of these behaviour of `accept(2)` is consistent: `sun_path` is nowhere to be found in the structure filled. The behaviour of `getsockname(2)` is consistent between different operating environments too, making all protocol specific details available.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't bound your client socket to an address.

You don't need to bind your client socket to an address for connect() to work; but, if you expect to access your client address in your server, then you do have to bind().

Make sense?

Just setup a call to bind() before you connect in your client. Make sure you the path you use for you client is valid and check for errors as normal.

Comment: Thanks! https://github.com/CarloWood/evio/commit/bfe006a6d33e2832c80b9971d53c01f5f50173cd